# Can't install Epsilon editor

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

I want to install epsilon editor on my machine. I have downloaded a package from their [site](https://www.lugaru.com/cgi-bin/send13.pl/eval/m) 
but when I install that package it is showing an error

```
I can't locate a suitable older version of Epsilon.
Specify the directory containing the older version on ./eupdate's
command line.  Example: ./eupdate /usr/local/epsilon10.00
Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package eupd13.16:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 eupd13.12:i386
 eupd13.16:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

please someone help me.

Comment: Very strange comment, @user535733, -1. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is stable and will be supported until 2021. Why OP should upgrade to newer non-LTS release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Epsilon History page](http://www.lugaru.com/history.html) it is bit outdated.

> May 2006 - Epsilon 13 Released
>   October 2003 - Epsilon 12 Released

But [main page](https://www.lugaru.com/cgi-bin/send13.pl/eval/m) has newer update date:

> Last updated: 30 January 2018

It is confusing.

But it starts normally if I download it as tar.bz2 archive:

```
wget https://www.lugaru.com/cgi-bin/send13.pl/eval/epsilon13eval.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf epsilon13eval.tar.bz2
cd epsilon13.16/
./bin/epsilon
```

And if I install it from deb-package:

```
wget https://www.lugaru.com/cgi-bin/send13.pl/eval/epsilon13eval-1.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi epsilon13eval-1.deb # will satisfy all dependencies
epsilon
```